# Javascript 'arr[index]' returning entire array instead of a single value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a discord bot.
One part where my discord bot works weirdly is when I do this particular statement:

```js
currentAnagramAnswer = movielist[Math.floor(Math.random() * movielist.length)].toLowerCase().split(" ").join('');
```

where `movielist` is an array of ~250 movies (string) that is filled by reading from a file.

Now, when I run this code locally, I get what I expect - A single element randomly selected from the array. But, when I push this to heroku and then run from heroku, instead of getting just one element, it returns me all elements (in lowercase, split and joined again according to the delimiters described above)

Note: I use `readFileSync` to fill my array. I have also tried using `async await` but haven't really been able to solve the problem.

Edit: When I print `currentAnagramAnswer`, the heroku logs show this

```
2020-04-23T08:19:31.343656+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theshawshankredemption

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343688+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegodfather

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343689+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegodfather:partii

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343689+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thedarkknight

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343689+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 12angrymen

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343690+00:00 app[Worker.1]: schindler'slist

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343690+00:00 app[Worker.1]: pulpfiction

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343690+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegood,thebadandtheugly

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343691+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thelordoftherings:thereturnoftheking

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343691+00:00 app[Worker.1]: fightclub

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343692+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thelordoftherings:thefellowshipofthering

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343692+00:00 app[Worker.1]: starwars:episodev-theempirestrikesback

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343693+00:00 app[Worker.1]: forrestgump

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343693+00:00 app[Worker.1]: inception

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343693+00:00 app[Worker.1]: oneflewoverthecuckoo'snest

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343693+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thelordoftherings:thetwotowers

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343694+00:00 app[Worker.1]: goodfellas

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343694+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thematrix

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343694+00:00 app[Worker.1]: starwars

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343694+00:00 app[Worker.1]: sevensamurai

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343695+00:00 app[Worker.1]: cityofgod

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343695+00:00 app[Worker.1]: se7en

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343695+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thesilenceofthelambs

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343695+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theusualsuspects

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343695+00:00 app[Worker.1]: it'sawonderfullife

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343696+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lifeisbeautiful

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343696+00:00 app[Worker.1]: léon:theprofessional

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343696+00:00 app[Worker.1]: onceuponatimeinthewest

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343696+00:00 app[Worker.1]: interstellar

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343697+00:00 app[Worker.1]: savingprivateryan

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343697+00:00 app[Worker.1]: americanhistoryx

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343697+00:00 app[Worker.1]: spiritedaway

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343697+00:00 app[Worker.1]: casablanca

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343698+00:00 app[Worker.1]: raidersofthelostark

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343698+00:00 app[Worker.1]: psycho

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343698+00:00 app[Worker.1]: citylights

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343698+00:00 app[Worker.1]: rearwindow

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343699+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theintouchables

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343699+00:00 app[Worker.1]: moderntimes

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343699+00:00 app[Worker.1]: terminator2:judgmentday

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343699+00:00 app[Worker.1]: whiplash

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343700+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegreenmile

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343700+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thepianist

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343700+00:00 app[Worker.1]: memento

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343700+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thedeparted

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343701+00:00 app[Worker.1]: gladiator

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343701+00:00 app[Worker.1]: apocalypsenow

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343701+00:00 app[Worker.1]: backtothefuture

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343702+00:00 app[Worker.1]: sunsetblvd.

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343703+00:00 app[Worker.1]: dr.strangeloveor:howilearnedtostopworryingandlovethebomb

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343703+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theprestige

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343703+00:00 app[Worker.1]: alien

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thelionking

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thelivesofothers

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegreatdictator

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: insideout

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: cinemaparadiso

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343704+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theshining

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343705+00:00 app[Worker.1]: pathsofglory

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343705+00:00 app[Worker.1]: djangounchained

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343705+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thedarkknightrises

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343705+00:00 app[Worker.1]: wall·e

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: americanbeauty

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: graveofthefireflies

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: aliens

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: citizenkane

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: northbynorthwest

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: princessmononoke

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343706+00:00 app[Worker.1]: vertigo

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343707+00:00 app[Worker.1]: oldeuboi

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343707+00:00 app[Worker.1]: dasboot

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343707+00:00 app[Worker.1]: m

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343707+00:00 app[Worker.1]: starwars:episodevi-returnofthejedi

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343707+00:00 app[Worker.1]: onceuponatimeinamerica

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: amélie

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: witnessfortheprosecution

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: reservoirdogs

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: braveheart

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: toystory3

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343708+00:00 app[Worker.1]: aclockworkorange

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: doubleindemnity

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: taxidriver

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: requiemforadream

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: tokillamockingbird

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lawrenceofarabia

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343709+00:00 app[Worker.1]: eternalsunshineofthespotlessmind

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343725+00:00 app[Worker.1]: fullmetaljacket

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343725+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thesting

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343726+00:00 app[Worker.1]: amadeus

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343726+00:00 app[Worker.1]: bicyclethieves

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343726+00:00 app[Worker.1]: singin'intherain

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343727+00:00 app[Worker.1]: montypythonandtheholygrail

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343727+00:00 app[Worker.1]: snatch.

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343727+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 2001:aspaceodyssey

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343727+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thekid

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343728+00:00 app[Worker.1]: l.a.confidential

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343728+00:00 app[Worker.1]: rashômon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343728+00:00 app[Worker.1]: forafewdollarsmore

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: toystory

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theapartment

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: inglouriousbasterds

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: allabouteve

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thetreasureofthesierramadre

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343729+00:00 app[Worker.1]: jodaeiyenaderazsimin

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343730+00:00 app[Worker.1]: indianajonesandthelastcrusade

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343730+00:00 app[Worker.1]: metropolis

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343730+00:00 app[Worker.1]: yojimbo

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343730+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thethirdman

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343730+00:00 app[Worker.1]: batmanbegins

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: scarface

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: somelikeithot

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: unforgiven

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 3idiots

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: up

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343731+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ragingbull

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: downfall

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: madmax:furyroad

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: jagten

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: chinatown

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegreatescape

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343732+00:00 app[Worker.1]: diehard

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: goodwillhunting

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: heat

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: onthewaterfront

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: pan'slabyrinth

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: mr.smithgoestowashington

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebridgeontheriverkwai

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: myneighbortotoro

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ran

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegoldrush

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ikiru

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theseventhseal

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343734+00:00 app[Worker.1]: bladerunner

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thesecretintheireyes

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: wildstrawberries

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegeneral

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lock,stockandtwosmokingbarrels

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theelephantman

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343735+00:00 app[Worker.1]: casino

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thewolfofwallstreet

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: howl'smovingcastle

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: warrior

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: grantorino

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: vforvendetta

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343736+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebiglebowski

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: rebecca

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: judgmentatnuremberg

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: abeautifulmind

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: coolhandluke

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thedeerhunter

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343737+00:00 app[Worker.1]: howtotrainyourdragon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: gonewiththewind

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: fargo

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: trainspotting

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ithappenedonenight

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: dialmformurder

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343738+00:00 app[Worker.1]: intothewild

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343739+00:00 app[Worker.1]: gonegirl

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343739+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thesixthsense

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343739+00:00 app[Worker.1]: rush

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343739+00:00 app[Worker.1]: findingnemo

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343739+00:00 app[Worker.1]: themaltesefalcon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: maryandmax

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: nocountryforoldmen

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thething

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: incendies

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: hotelrwanda

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: killbill:vol.1

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343740+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lifeofbrian

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343741+00:00 app[Worker.1]: platoon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343741+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thewagesoffear

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343745+00:00 app[Worker.1]: butchcassidyandthesundancekid

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343745+00:00 app[Worker.1]: therewillbeblood

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343745+00:00 app[Worker.1]: network

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: touchofevil

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: the400blows

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: standbyme

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 12yearsaslave

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theprincessbride

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: anniehall

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343746+00:00 app[Worker.1]: persona

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegrandbudapesthotel

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: amoresperros

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: inthenameofthefather

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: milliondollarbaby

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: ben-hur

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343747+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegrapesofwrath

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343748+00:00 app[Worker.1]: hachi:adog'stale

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343762+00:00 app[Worker.1]: nausicaäofthevalleyofthewind

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343762+00:00 app[Worker.1]: shutterisland

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343762+00:00 app[Worker.1]: diabolique

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343763+00:00 app[Worker.1]: sincity

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343763+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thewizardofoz

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343763+00:00 app[Worker.1]: gandhi

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343763+00:00 app[Worker.1]: stalker

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343764+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebourneultimatum

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343764+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebestyearsofourlives

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343764+00:00 app[Worker.1]: donniedarko

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343765+00:00 app[Worker.1]: relatossalvajes

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343765+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 8½

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343765+00:00 app[Worker.1]: strangersonatrain

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343765+00:00 app[Worker.1]: jurassicpark

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343766+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theavengers

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343766+00:00 app[Worker.1]: beforesunrise

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343766+00:00 app[Worker.1]: twelvemonkeys

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343766+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theterminator

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343767+00:00 app[Worker.1]: infernalaffairs

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343767+00:00 app[Worker.1]: jaws

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343767+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebattleofalgiers

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343767+00:00 app[Worker.1]: groundhogday

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343767+00:00 app[Worker.1]: memoriesofmurder

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343768+00:00 app[Worker.1]: guardiansofthegalaxy

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343768+00:00 app[Worker.1]: monsters,inc.

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343768+00:00 app[Worker.1]: harrypotterandthedeathlyhallows:part2

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343768+00:00 app[Worker.1]: throneofblood

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343769+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thetrumanshow

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343769+00:00 app[Worker.1]: fannyandalexander

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343769+00:00 app[Worker.1]: barrylyndon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343770+00:00 app[Worker.1]: rocky

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343770+00:00 app[Worker.1]: dogdayafternoon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343770+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theimitationgame

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343770+00:00 app[Worker.1]: yipman

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343771+00:00 app[Worker.1]: theking'sspeech

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343771+00:00 app[Worker.1]: highnoon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343771+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lahaine

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343771+00:00 app[Worker.1]: afistfulofdollars

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343772+00:00 app[Worker.1]: piratesofthecaribbean:thecurseoftheblackpearl

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343772+00:00 app[Worker.1]: notorious

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343772+00:00 app[Worker.1]: castleinthesky

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343772+00:00 app[Worker.1]: prisoners

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343773+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thehelp

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343773+00:00 app[Worker.1]: who'safraidofvirginiawoolf?

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343773+00:00 app[Worker.1]: romanholiday

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343773+00:00 app[Worker.1]: spring,summer,fall,winter...andspring

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343774+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thenightofthehunter

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343774+00:00 app[Worker.1]: beautyandthebeast

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343774+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lastrada

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343774+00:00 app[Worker.1]: papillon

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343775+00:00 app[Worker.1]: x-men:daysoffuturepast

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343775+00:00 app[Worker.1]: beforesunset

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343775+00:00 app[Worker.1]: anatomyofamurder

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thehustler

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thegraduate

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: thebigsleep

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: underground

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: elitesquad:theenemywithin

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343776+00:00 app[Worker.1]: gangsofwasseypur

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343777+00:00 app[Worker.1]: lagaan:onceuponatimeinindia

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343777+00:00 app[Worker.1]: paris,texas

2020-04-23T08:19:31.343777+00:00 app[Worker.1]: akira
```

I call `movielist = data.readMovieList('./movielist.txt');` right above the `currentAnagramAnswer` line.

My `readMovieList` is in another file

```js
    const readMovieList = (movieLoc) => {
    try{
        var movie = fs.readFileSync(movieLoc, 'utf8');
        movieListArr = movie.split('\r\n');
        return movieListArr;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("Error reading file: ", e.stack)
    }}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you populate the `movielist` array?

Comment: why do you need split and join at the end?

Comment: Can we get some output from heroku?

Comment: @EugenSunic The inputs are space separated so I am trying to remove the spaces